# Brezis exercise, under what condition does $f$ belongs to $L_p(\mathbb{R^n})$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

**Brezis excercise 4.1**: I am asked to show under what conditions does $f(x)=\{1+|x|^\alpha\}^{-1}\{1+|\log|x||^\beta\}^{-1}$ belong to $L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $\alpha,\beta>0$..

I know that for $f$ to belong is must show that $\int_{(\mathbb{R^n})}|f|^p<\infty$, so far I got this:

$$|f(x)|^p=\dfrac{1}{|1+|x|^\alpha|^p|1+|\log|x||^\beta|^p}$$ however I don't know what to do after this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a radial function, so after changing to polar coordinates, it comes down to whether a 1-dimensional integral converges. My hint: work out the case $\beta=0$ first.

Comment: I will give it a try, however, two points. 1. $\beta$ is supposed to be nonzero. 2. In order to apply the polar coordinates I know, $f$ must be "summable" meaning the integral of it mod is finite. which is what I must show i think.

Comment: 1. I'm aware that in your actual problem $\beta>0$, but the situation here is actually mostly controlled by $\alpha$. 2. As long as the integral makes sense (the integrand is measurable and the integral isn't a $\infty - \infty$ form), you can definitely change variables freely.

Comment: I used polar coordinates and got: $$\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}f=w_{n-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{r^{\alpha p -n+1}(log (r))^{\beta p}}$$ I assume that this converges for some special values, where can I read more about this?

Comment: If you set $\beta=0$ then the situation should be quite obvious. Now for $\beta>0$, you can use a comparison argument to reduce it to the $\beta=0$ case, except when $\alpha p - n + 1$ is one particular value. If you show you can get to this point, then I'll explain what the deal is with $\beta$.